# Trabalhando com limite de ID em grandes volumes

Tags: mysql, sql, banco-de-dados, modelagem

Tenho em mente algumas questões sobre grandes volumes de dados no *MYSQL*, referentes ao limite de *ID*. Vou dar como exemplo um *ID* tipo `tinyint` para simplificar a explicação. No exemplo o campo `tinyint` aceita *127* registros.

Supondo que entrem 100 novos registros, isso cria *IDs* de *1 à 100*. Eventualmente os *50* primeiros registros serão deletados, então terei apenas *50* registros com *IDs* de *50 à 100* e alocação para mais *27* registros, o que resulta em *77* registros. Ou seja, temos *77* registros apenas, em uma tabela que deveria receber até *127* registros.

Sei que o *MYSQL* não retrocede para ocupar as posições vagas, a questão é outra. Não é raro ter que remover entradas, e com isso perde-se um espaço na tabela.

---

1. Como seria uma forma eficiente de alocar a quantidade real de registros sem perder os *IDs* reservados?
2. Usar `bigint` no lugar de `int` que é o comumente mais usado, só aumentaria o tempo de se alcançar o limite?

<sub>Desconsiderar qualquer erro do cálculos acima :)</sub>

Comment: A meu ver sua dúvida é um tanto equivocada... Quando você seta um tipo de campo para uma coluna, você não está setando a quantidade de registro na tabela, a tabela pode conter 'N' registros. O que voce está setando é o tamanho do tipo de coluna, no caso o tinyint vai até 127. SUa tabela suportaria quantos registros quisesse se este campo nao for PK. o que não é suportado é o campo PK com registro duplicado, com isso limita sua tabela. O que pode fazer é a medida q seu banco for crescendo alterar para int e posteriormente bigint....

Comment: @MichelSimões, ao citar ID, fica subentendido que se trata do PK da tabela

Comment: A resposta pode incluir alternativas ao `int` e ao `bigint`?

Comment: @CiganoMorrisonMendez, mas o uso de `bigint` somente aumentaria o 'tempo' para alcançar o limite de entradas, correto?

Comment: @PapaCharlie Sim. Vou escrever uma resposta com outra alternativa que você não tenha imaginado ainda.

Comment: Ia, na verdade. A resposta do @FlavioGranato era o que eu ia responder.

Comment: @CiganoMorrisonMendez, fiz um comentário na resposta. Procede o risco de colisão?

Comment: Não. [Veja isto](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier#Random_UUID_probability_of_duplicates).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Não compartilho da simpatia do UUID. Acho que é útil em alguns casos mas tem que ter motivo para usá-lo e não acho que seja o caso. O UUID tem vários problemas que não vem ao caso aqui, mas só o consumo de espaço já é um deles.

Eu usaria o `BIGINT` mesmo. Eu duvido que você venha ter problemas com isto. Fisicamente não poderá ter esta quantidade de linhas na tabela nem mesmo nas próximas décadas. Se fica deletando muitas linhas eu acho que compensaria ter um mecanismo que compactação dos IDs que rodasse periodicamente. Duvido que precise, mas precisando teria que *renumerar* todas as linhas fazendo os devidos ajustes onde os IDs foram usados em outras tabelas. Sim, claro, isto não é simples e em alguns casos compensa, em outros não. Lembrando que se um dia tiver que trocar o tipo da coluna, vai ter trabalho semelhante.

Reforço que eu duvido que seja necessário fazer todo este mecanismo, mas se quiser evitar isto, acho que é melhor solução criar uma combinação de colunas para aumentar o número máximo, desde que feito isto antecipadamente. Também pode usar um tipo de *string*, o que teria que fazer com o UUID, e controlar o incremento pelo próprio banco de dados.

Se precisa economizar espaço mesmo, aí além de usar o menor tipo possível, se tem muitas *deleções*, e os IDs deletados precisam ser reaproveitados logo para não estourar, eu criaria uma [*free-list*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_list) reaproveitando as linhas ao invés de removê-las. Cada vem que tiver que remover, marca a linha como removida (uma coluna própria para isto que será usada para filtrar) e coloca o ID em uma tabela que guarda uma lista de IDs disponíveis. Quando for inserir, se tiver um ID nesta lista, remove ele da lista e reaproveita a linha limpando ela totalmente e gravando os novos dados. Tem que saber fazer isto do jeito correto especialmente em ambientes concorrentes, como é comum acontecer.

Nenhuma é boa, mas está aí algumas alternativas do que pode ser feito, além do UUID, que não deixa de ser uma opção.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/SQL/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Otima resposta. Lembrando que se a opção for a free-list, existe um compromisso muito claro. Você terá mais passos de processamento para obter um ID. Precisa realmente verificar a necessidade.

Comment: Grande resposta. *Tem que saber fazer isto do jeito correto[..]*, sem dúvida. Vou procurar mais referências, mas me soou bem agradável esse esquema. Obrigado big.

Answer (score 4):

Se o ID ao qual você se refere for uma surrogate key (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surrogate_key), ou seja, um valor que exista apenas para dar identidade  a cada registro, não tendo nenhuma relação com sua aplicação, então você não deveria se preocupar com isso. Coloque bigint e fique tranquilo. Não se preocupe com reaproveitamento de IDs que foram perdidos por exclusões, isso dará muito mais trabalho pra benefício 0.

Obviamente, tudo tem um limite, mas o bigint sem sinal do MYSQL vai até 18446744073709551615 (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/integer-types.html). É muito registro na tabela para alcançar isso e, caso sua aplicação atinja, aí será necessário uma outra forma de resolver, talvez outra tabela com mesma estrutura que comporte os outros 18446744073709551615 registros.

Answer (score 4):

Indico a utilização do UUID já que ele é único.

Normalmente ordenamos os dados por outras colunas e não pelo id. Para sabermos quem vem antes de quem é só ordenar pela data de criação se tiver e caso necessário.

Comment: Até onde li, o `UUID` é criado com base no MAC, data e hora, seria difícil uma colisão, mas não impossível. Inclusive considerei essa alternativa.

Comment: Você estaria utilizando multiprocessamento e um altíssimo volume de dados? Acho que este seria o caso em que eu consideraria alguma coisa quando o UUID. Meu exemplo se baseia no meu sistema de processamento de arquivos xml que recebemos de fornecedores, temos 30 threads e fazemos inserções a cada 5 ms, UUID tem nos garantido muito bem...

Comment: Entendo, não critiquei sua resposta, dei upvote nela. O que citei foi a possibilidade de colisão, o que seria resolvido verificando o `UUID`.

Comment: Não leve para este lado, somente complementei indicando um caso de sucesso da implementação que indiquei.