# Atualizar ID serial quando uma tabela estiver NULL

Tags: java, postgresql

Estou fazendo um programa desktop em java, com o ID de um produto sendo incrementado automaticamente por SERIAL.

Porém, quando eu excluo algum elemento ou todos, o valor da sequência se mantém no último que foi adicionado em diante, e eu tenho que ir lá no banco e alterar esse valor a mão.

Alguém tem ideia de uma trigger ou se eu consigo mudar isso nas configurações da própria sequência mesmo?

Comment: Pq vc precisa resetar o serial?

Comment: Porque quando eu excluo algo da tabela ele não atualiza o id.

Comment: Não atualiza o id, seria o que exatamente? o que vc esperaria?

Comment: Eu excluo um produto com id 1, o próximo produto que eu cadastrar no sistema fica com id 2. A mesma coisa se eu apagar uma tabela com 600 produtos, se eu cadastrar um novo produto ele começa por 601.

Comment: Esse é o comportamento esperado, você não 'reaproveita' ids, seja por existirem registros relacionados em outras tabelas e principalmente pelo esforço de reordenar todos os registros.

Comment: Relacionada: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/78544/3084

Comment: Compartilho do mesmo que o @rray disse e reforço que tentar reaproveitar IDs é algo que exige um esforço completamente desnecessário.

Comment: Qual o comportamento esperado caso você tenha os ids, 1 a 10 e você exclui o 7? cadastrar o novo como 7, ou reajustar todos os seguintes para o próximo ser o 10?

Comment: Isso é uma situação pela qual quase todo iniciante em bancos de dados passa, achar que está perdendo algo "desperdiçando" IDs serial/autoincrement e que reaproveitar elas vai trazer algum beneficío. @Joana a não ser que você tenha um problema _realmente_ especifíco esse reaproveitamento é uma má ideia, caso tenha por favor adicione na pergunta porque eu sinceramente nunca vi um e estou curioso ;p

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Este é o comportamento esperado de um campo autoincremento de um DB, não faz muito sentido você procurar um ID excluído e forçar o DB adicionar este ID no novo cadastro, você vai perder muito desempenho, pois imagine sua tabela com 2000 itens ou mais, isso não é uma boa prática.

Comment: Entendi. Realmente não tinha olhado por esse ângulo, só estava preocupada com os valores que jogaria fora. Sou iniciante ainda e é sempre bom melhorar nas práticas de programação. Obrigada!

Comment: Magina, estamos aqui para ajudar um ao outro, pois todos aqui um dia ja foi iniciante.

Answer (score 0):

Pode resetar o valor de um campo serial(sequence), com

```
ALTER SEQUENCE nome_da_sequence RESTART WITH 1
```

Baseado em: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5272164/1342547

Comment: Já fiz isso! Queria saber se tem uma maneira dele identificar a falta de um produto com determinado id e não deixar esse valor vazio.

Comment: ;) você pode até ter feito mas não citou isso na pergunta, não posso adivinhar, por isso é importante citar as(algumas) tentativas(mesmo que erradas) de resolver o problema, assim todo mundo o que não fazer.

Comment: "...Porém, quando eu excluo algum elemento ou todos, o valor da sequência se mantém no último que foi adicionado em diante, e eu tenho que ir lá no banco e alterar esse valor a mão." Pensei que tinha ficado claro assim.

Comment: @Joana, também não entendi extamente o que você quer, mas se o que você quer é reaproveitar IDs que foram utilizados anteriormente e depois apagados, esqueça essa ideia, isso é receita para problema. IDs foram feitos pra isso mesmo... deixa incrementar a vontade, se houver "buracos", não esquenta, isso não faz diferença.

Comment: @Joana você pode criar um método chamado `resetSerial(String tabela)` onde chama esse comando. Ou se quiser algo mais automatizado pode listar todas as sequences em checkbox e marcar quais deseja resetar o valor.