# PHP problema com o INT do SQL

Tags: php, sql

Estou a fazer um `form` que envia os dados por `AJAX` e depois insere, até ai tudo bem. Só que o valor máximo do `INT` em SQL é de 2147483647, e o campo que tenho tem no máximo 11 dígitos que pode ir até 99999999999, qual a melhor opção para contornar este problema? mudar para `VARCHAR`?

Comment: long não serve?

Comment: Veja se [**essa**](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/78544/trabalhando-com-limite-de-id-em-grandes-volumes) questão ajuda.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Podes usar o tipo de dados `BIGINT`.